# How to debug to find where a value is changing in C#/ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging

A project I inherited uses a [`DynamicControlsPlaceholder`](http://www.denisbauer.com/Home/DynamicControlsPlaceholder).  Within the placeholder, the code adds controls that render out to

```
<table> <-- HtmlTable
   <tr> <-- HtmlTableRow
     <td> <-- HtmlTableCell
       Question <-- LiteralControl
     </td> 
     ...
   </tr>
   ...
</table>
```

The `DynamicControlsPlaceholder` correctly stores the structure in `ViewState` and correctly restores the structure (though the `<td>` has a `LiteralControl` with an empty text property rather than "Question").

Some time later, in

```
System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState()
  System.Web.UI.Control.LoadViewStateRecursive(object savedState)
    System.Web.UI.Control.LoadChildViewStateByIndex(System.Collections.ArrayList childState)
      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadViewStateRecursive(object savedState)
        System.Web.UI.Control.LoadChildViewStateByIndex(System.Collections.ArrayList childState)
          ... (lots of recursive calls) ...
            System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.LoadViewState(object savedState)
              System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow.HtmlTableCellControlCollection.Add(System.Web.UI.Control child)
```

an exception is thrown stating that an `HtmlTableRow` cannot contain a `LiteralControl` child, as `HtmlTableRows` may only contain `HtmlTableCells`.  I stored a reference to the `HtmlTableRow` using the immediate window in VS's debugger during the recreation of the structure.

As I said before, during the creation, the structure is correct, aside from the `LiteralControl` not having a value.  By the time the exception is thrown, the `HtmlTableRow` has lost its child controls and gained an `Attribute` called `innerhtml = "Question"`.  My guess is that it (whatever *it* is--the `ViewState`?) is seeing the attribute and converting it to a `LiteralControl`, and then failing since it's lost its `HtmlTableCell`.

I don't know how to debug any further here.  I thought maybe there was a way to set my variable (`x`) in the Immediate Window, and then set a Data Breakpoint for when `x.Cells[0]` changes or something, but it looks like Data Breakpoints are only for unmanaged code.

Any ideas on how to unblock my debugging?  Thanks.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on a line in the function you are trying to debug, then right click the red dot on the left (that marks the breakpoint) and select "Condition."  Here you can check for when a value changes or when a condition is true.  The breakpoint won't be hit until that time.

Comment: The issue is that I don't know what function to put the breakpoint in.  It's not changing value in my code.  At least not that I can tell, and certainly not when the structure is being built by `DynamicControlsPlaceHolder`.